Numeric footnotes in the title page, Corresponding author identified with an asterisk
I am required to have in the title page the list of the authors with numeric superscripts, and following one of the forum's thread I did that using the following lines of code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    
\author{author\thanks{xxx} \thanks{Corresponding author} and author\thanks{xxx}}
\title{TITLE
}

\maketitle

\end{document}

However, this transforms all footnotes of the title page into numeric footnotes, while I would need the footnote identifying the Corresponding Author to be an asterisk.

Any chance do you know an easy way to do that? It should look like this:

Many thanks
